# groovy script / java code to get distinct users from resultset

Tags: java, groovy

Hi I run a simple select query in oracle over a table and get a resultset. like `select username, responsibility, project from mytable.`
The resultset  contains user details. there are multiple rows returned for each username with different values for responsibility and project.
Now I want to get a list of lists from this resultset which has one List per username and distinct values are concatenated in a comma seperated string.
So if Sam has multiple entries in the resultset then the output of my operation should give me:

```
UserList =
["Sam", "responsibility1,responsibility2,responsibility3...", "dept1,dept2,dept3.."],
[Some other User],
[and so on..]
```

Later I will write this to a csv file.
I cannot do this in the query itself for compatibility reasons, we have to support multiple databases, versions in future.
How do I do this in java  or groovy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Java is quite easy.
You need a class to model each user.
You need a Map of username to User.
Each User contains a List of responsibility and a List of departments.
Then you iterate your resultset, find the User from the map on each row and add the responsibility and department to that User

Do you need the code or is that good enough?

HTH

Edit: Here's some Java starting code:
(Not checked for syntax or mistakes ;] )

```
public class User {
    private final List<String> responsibility = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final List<String> department = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...standard getters and setters
}

// Your code to do the read
public void executeRead() {

    ... obtain the resultset somehow here

    Map<String, User> usernameToUser = new HashMap<String, User>():
    while (rs.next) {
        String username = rs.getString("username");
        User user = usernameToUser.get(username);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User(); // Create and remember a user the first time you see them
            usernameToUser.put(username, user);
        }
        String responsiblity = rs.getString("responsiblity");
        String department = rs.getString("department");
        user.addResponsibility(responsibility);
        user.addDepartment(department);
    }
    rs.close();

    // Now you have the data structure of users in memory you can output
    // it in whichever format you like e.g. HTML, CSV, etc
    // Probably best to do this step in a totally separate place that can
    // be switched out for a different output format in future.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip David. The only reason I asked groovy was closures make it one line code..the code below removes the duplicates in sumMap and sums up the other field in the map for that user.. instead of sum, I need string concat.     def finalMap = sumMap.groupBy{ it[1] }.collect{ k, v -> [ (k) : v*.first().sum() ] }.sum()

Comment: Interesting groovy code, not done much groovy specific syntax myself. The java code is a lot more than 1 line you know - are you looking for a 1 liner solution?

Comment: Made a quick attempt at some code in an edit to the answer - more code than Groovy but easier to understand I reckon?